# Counting relationship in sequelize returnings 1 instead of 0

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have the following test case for sequelize where I am attempting to return the count of a relationship on a model.

```
test('Tag with file count', async () => {
      const tagOne = await db.Tag.create({
        label: 'One'
      })

      const tagTwo = await db.Tag.create({
        label: 'Two'
      })

      const tagThree = await db.Tag.create({
        label: 'Three'
      })

      const tagFour = await db.Tag.create({
        label: 'Four'
      })

      const tagFive = await db.Tag.create({
        label: 'Five'
      })

      const fileOne = await db.File.create()

      const fileTwo = await db.File.create()

      await fileOne.setTags([tagOne, tagTwo, tagFour])

      await fileTwo.setTags([tagOne, tagTwo, tagThree])

      const output = await db.Tag.findAll({
        attributes: {
          include: [
            [Sequelize.fn('COUNT', 'Files.id'), 'fileCount']
          ]
        },
        include: [
          {
            model: db.File,
            as: 'files',
            attributes: [],
            duplicate: false
          }
        ],
        group: 'Tag.id',
        order: [
          [Sequelize.literal('`fileCount`'), 'DESC']
        ]
      })

      expect(output.length).toBe(5)
      expect(output.find(tag => tag.label === tagOne.label).dataValues.fileCount).toBe(2)
      expect(output.find(tag => tag.label === tagTwo.label).dataValues.fileCount).toBe(2)
      expect(output.find(tag => tag.label === tagThree.label).dataValues.fileCount).toBe(1)
      expect(output.find(tag => tag.label === tagFour.label).dataValues.fileCount).toBe(1)
      expect(output.find(tag => tag.label === tagFive.label).dataValues.fileCount).toBe(0)
    })
```

For tagFive, I expected the column fileCount to be 0 but it returns 1. For others it seems to return the correct file count.

Is there an option missing in findAll or a bug?

#### Edit

I get the following query generated

```
Executing (default): SELECT `Tag`.`id`, 
`Tag`.`label`, 
`Tag`.`slug`, 
`Tag`.`createdAt`, 
`Tag`.`updatedAt`, COUNT('Files.id') AS `fileCount`, 
`files->FileTags`.`createdAt` AS `files.FileTags.createdAt`, 
`files->FileTags`.`updatedAt` AS `files.FileTags.updatedAt`, 
`files->FileTags`.`FileId` AS `files.FileTags.FileId`, 
`files->FileTags`.`TagId` AS `files.FileTags.TagId` 
FROM `Tags` AS `Tag` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `FileTags` AS `files->FileTags` 
ON `Tag`.`id` = `files->FileTags`.`TagId` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Files` AS `files` 
ON `files`.`id` = `files->FileTags`.`FileId` 
GROUP BY `Tag`.`id` ORDER BY `fileCount` DESC;
```

Though there's so many alias and I am not comfortable with joins.

Comment: did you turn on the logging for your sequelize queries in the connection object so that you can see what query is being generated for the findAll? I suspect that will lead you to find out that your findAll is not generating the query you think it is..

Comment: Updating the question with the said query as too long for the comment section

Comment: Re-reading the query, the only observation I make is that TagId should be tagId and FileId should be fileId. But I am not sure if this means anything for this issue.

Comment: I wonder if it’s because of the way you went at it, from Tag instead of from Tag files... it is probably getting a null for the Files.id field and counting it because technically null is a valid value... what you want is that row to not even be returned, not returned with a null....try running that query in your database tools, whatever you use... pgAdmin if it’s Postgres..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made a few changes into something that would work in my database with a similar structure...  This did return me some 0 count rows, however this is postgres i am running it on, and you are clearly using something different

```
SELECT tag.id, 
COUNT(story.id) AS fileCount
FROM tag 
LEFT OUTER JOIN story_tag
ON tag.name = story_tag.tag 
LEFT OUTER JOIN story 
ON story.id = story_tag.story_id 
GROUP BY tag.id ORDER BY fileCount DESC;
```

Comment: correct, I am using sqlite, I'll have a try to see if I can reach a similar result. Did you use raw query or used sequelize syntax?

Comment: I just used raw query for this... I suspect raw is a better way to achieve your results actually, there is a pile of unnecessary fields in that query Sequelize generated, which is understandable since you were using full models

Comment: Adapted your query into a raw sequelize query which works. I wish it could be written via the plugin syntax.

Comment: I bet it can but maybe not from the direction you came at it, I will take a look at it tomorrow when I am back at a computer and see how I could do it with my similar tables...

Comment: Thanks for your time. Really appreciate. I am trying as well to work around the syntax to see what can be done to have it output closer to yours. I don't see any means to perform manual joins from sequelize docs from the model.

Comment: Surprisingly, I did it with the following change: ```Sequelize.fn``` to ```Sequelize.literal``` and eventually writing ```'COUNT(`files`.`id`)'``` instead did it. But I am still unable to remove further excess from the query.

Comment: I think you can do that part by specifying particular attributes that are necessary... however, that does not work well with data loader for query batching... That will not affect performance greatly anyway so i’d say you hit a home run

Comment: The thing is from what I read, ```attributes: []``` should have ignored all columns from the join/relationship, but still include createdAt, updatedAt. It's not a deal breaker but, if it would improve performance, I'd work for it.